# Calculate date of last day of month before a target date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I can add any number of months to a date:

```
strtotime("+ 1 months", '2017-01-31') // result: 2017-03-03
```

But I want to do this without going to the next month.

in this case I want the result 2017-02-28, that is, the last day of the month *before* the target month.

Comment: Clarify question based on comments by the OP, used a less generic title

Comment: Rephrase for clarity

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of overcomplicating in these answers. You want the last day of the month before your target month, which is also always going to be 1 day before the first day of the target month. This can be expressed quite simply:

```
$months = 1;
$relativeto = '2017-01-31';
echo date(
    'Y-m-d',
    strtotime(
        '-1 day',
        strtotime(
            date(
                'Y-m-01',
                strtotime("+ $months months", strtotime($relativeto))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to accomplish this, specifically the [modify()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method.

```
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable on SO. Please consider providing a little more information, such as an example, and a brief explanation. Web links are often broken on the web all the time and providing some substantive part of what the link talks about is necessary for SO answers to remain useful over time.

Comment: $date = new DateTime('2017-01-31');
$date->modify('+1 month');
resultat : 2017-03-03

Comment: The point is the the OP don't want the exact 1 month ahead date, but the enddate for the next month (it seems) - you can still get this via DateTime, but it will need a bit more formatting/modification.

Comment: The only solution is to deal case by case ??

Comment: Just to be clear, this answer doesn't actually address the problem at hand, because the use of `DateTime::modify` here does the **same exact thing** as `strtotime("+1 month")`. You just happened to use a date that won't overflow (thereby completely subverting the OP's real question).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DateTime object like so:

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime('2017-01-31');
$dateTime->add(new \DateInterval('P1M'));

$result = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, because it has the same exact result as using `strtotime`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize until after I had answered he wanted the beginning of the month. I was going to suggest using Carbon, but he seems to not want to use DateTime, and somebody posted a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea here is not to allow the date to overflow into the next month, which PHP does, then you'll have to impose that constraint in your logic.

One approach is to check the modified month against the given month before returning the updated date.

```
function nextMonth(DateTimeImmutable $date) {
    $nextMonth = $date->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
    $diff = $nextMonth->diff($date);
    if ($diff->d > 0) {
        $nextMonth = $nextMonth->sub(new DateInterval("P{$diff->d}D"));
    }
    return $nextMonth;
}

$date = new DateTimeImmutable("2017-01-31");
$nextMonth = nextMonth($date);
echo "{$date->format('Y-m-d')} - {$nextMonth->format('Y-m-d')}\n";
//2017-01-31 - 2017-02-28


$date = new DateTimeImmutable("2017-10-31");
$nextMonth = nextMonth($date);
echo "{$date->format('Y-m-d')} - {$nextMonth->format('Y-m-d')}\n";
//2017-10-31 - 2017-11-30
```

The `nextMonth()` function in the example above, imposes the constraint of not overflowing into the next month. Note that what PHP actually does is try to find the corresponding day, in the following consecutive number of months added, not *just* add a given number of months to the existing date. I simply undo this last part by subtracting any additional days beyond the 1 month interval in the function above.

So for example, `strtotime("+1 month")` for the date `"2017-01-31"`, tells PHP find the 31st day that is +1 month from `"2017-01-31"`. But of course, there are only 28 days in February, so PHP goes into March and counts up 3 more days to compensate.

In other words, it's not just *add +1 month* to this date, but *add +1 month* to this date **and** *arrive at the same day of the month as is in the given date*. Which is where the overflow happens.

### Update

Since you've now made it clear that you actually want the last day of the month (not necessarily the same day of the next month without the overflow provision) you should instead just explicitly set the day of the month.

```
function nextMonth(DateTimeImmutable $date) {
    $nextMonth = $date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('n') + 1, 1);
    $nextMonth = $date->setDate($nextMonth->format('Y'), $nextMonth->format('n'), $nextMonth->format('t'));
    return $nextMonth;
}

$date = new DateTimeImmutable("2017-02-28");
$nextMonth = nextMonth($date);
echo "{$date->format('Y-m-d')} - {$nextMonth->format('Y-m-d')}\n";
// 2017-02-28 - 2017-03-31
```

Comment: but : $date = new DateTimeImmutable("2017-02-28");
$nextMonth = nextMonth($date);
echo "{$date->format('Y-m-d')} - {$nextMonth->format('Y-m-d')}\n";
//2017-02-28 - 2017-03-28 i want the resultat 2017-03-31

Comment: OK, you definitely didn't specify that in your question. There was no reason for me to blindly assume you always wanted the last day of the month following the month of the given date. Since you explicitly supply an actual day of the month. In that case just simply set the day of the month to the last day.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your newly elaborated requirements.